# Wordpress Timber merge terms from two taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, twig, taxonomy, timber

I see that Timber will allow a merged list of terms from all taxonomies. But is there a way to merge a list from two taxomomies?

This code works for me:

`{% for term in post.terms('topics') %}`

This works, but loads only the first taxonomy listed:

`{% for term in post.terms('topics','regions') %}`

This fails:

`{% for term in post.terms(array('topics','regions')) %}`

In a merged list, preferably with a sort by alpha. The [Timber docs](https://github.com/jarednova/timber/wiki/TimberPost#terms) give these instructions `terms($tax = 'any', $merge = true)` and show how one taxonomy can be specified (default is "all") but not how two might be specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@slam I think you just need to use Twig's array syntax to make this work:

```
{% for term in post.terms(['topics', 'regions']) %}
```

Give that a shot and lemme know!

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! Timber's docs still seem a bit thin and I can miss stuff like this. Any chance the term list can also be sorted by count field?